# How to build PHP MVC with AJAX support

Tags: php, ajax, model-view-controller

I am working on a personal Framework/Library with PHP, Javascript, CSS.

Plan on using MVC method.

Will have Themes and Templates

A Theme is a wrapper that Template files are embeded into...

```
<html>
    <header> Header area </header> 

    comtent template

    <footer> Footer section </footer>
</html>
```

and a Template is a `view` that is eventually included into the Theme file.

I know most people just simply include a header and footer but there is something about this approach of a Theme file that wraps Template files that attracts me for a while now. ( I haven't tried it out yet)

So using MVC let's assume I access a page `domain.com/users/page/2` this would simply build the page 2 of a user list or something.  Pretty straight forward.

Now let's assume this same application uses AJAX to load in `domain.com/users/page/2` instead of loading the whole `Theme` file and embedding all the `Template` files inside it...the `Theme` is already loaded so it should just fetch the content of the page without the `Theme wrapper file`

So if am AJAX request is sent, I realize I need to detect it in my MVC code, so I will have a Class Property that is True or False for the request being AJAX or Not

I am just trying to make sure I am on the right path, is there anything else I need to check or I am overlooking for this to possibly work?

Is this how the big frameworks do it?

I am thinking I should probably make it where I can set how the result is returned, like if returned to an AJAX request, maybe I should have an option to get it as pure HTML, XML, JSON?

Sorry if this seems really basic, I am not used to using the whole MVC, I fully understand it though.  So in the past to make an AJAX request I would generally just point to a separate file like `processing.php` that would just return the response for that AJAX request.  Now that I am routing everything through a single file and building the page from there I just want to make sure I handle the AJAX request properly with this

Comment: No need to answer here, you're right :)

Comment: Usually, AJAX calls some controller's method, that in turns echoes the appropriate view (i.e., the ajax response to be printed on page. In your case, it might mean loading a determined Template); the "big frameworks" I saw (CodeIgniter,Kohana, Yii) do like this; among the three I mentioned, Yii has a nice built in ajax class you can look into for inspiration, but it's not necessary to have it. Summing up, fire an ajax request to a controller the same as you once did to a single php page.